# Execution Order for the ApiController

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Is there something like this for the common method order?

http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-filesystemfile.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-46-38-WebApiStackDiagramsNew/6428.ASP.NET_5F00_MVC4_5F00_WebAPI_5F00_StackDiagram_5F00_Future.jpg

My Web Api solution has now a new order in the execution of some methods since I upgraded from Beta/RC version to RTM version.
(Its not the reverse order of message handler execution)

Earlier this method of the APIControllers was called:

```
protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
{
}
```

Before the filtermethods of my AuthorizationFilter

```
public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
}
```

After RTM the OnAuthorization is called before Initialize().
Are there some informations about the execution order of the ApiController methods and the changes after RTM release?

Comment: huh? where does InitializeProcadController come from? There has been no such a thing inside the source code of the project so far, AFAIK.

Comment: sorry I mean the "Initialize()" method

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Assuming the request goes into the ApiController scope, the operation order is as below:

- The `ExecuteAsync` method of the `ApiController` is invoked.
- The `Initialize` method of the `ApiController` is invoked.
- The registered Action Selector is retrieved.
- The `SelectAction` method of the registered action selector is invoked. If only one action method is matched, the pipeline continues.
- All registered Filters for the selected action is retrieved.
- The Authorization Filters are called. The authorization filter can decide either to let the pipeline to continue executing or to terminate the pipeline.
- If Authorization Filters didn't terminate the request, action parameter bindings are performed.
- `ApiController.ModelState` is set.
- Action Filters are invoked. The Action Filters can decide either to let the pipeline to continue executing or terminate the pipeline.
- If Action Filters didn't terminate the request, registered Action Invoker is retrieved.
- The `InvokeActionAsync` method of the registered Action Invoker is called to invoked the selected action method.
- Note: If any exception occurs from the execution of the Authorization Filters to the execution of the action method, the exception filters are be called.

There are a few more things which happen in between but this is very close to a complete view. Check out the [`ApiController` source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/436ae9643c21#src/System.Web.Http/ApiController.cs) for more information.

Comment: And this is why OperationHandlers were really cool.  What a mess.

Comment: I found OperationHandlers on google, but not how I register my custom OperationHandler...

Comment: BTW: Authorization Filters are called before the generic "normal" filters.

Comment: @user437899 Firstly, I'm not sure what u mean by 'normal' filters cuz all filters are normal. Secondly, yes, Authorization Filters are called first inside the controller pipeline as I indicated in my answer.

Comment: Useful: [ASP.NET Web API 2: HTTP Message Lifecycle poster](https://www.asp.net/media/4071077/aspnet-web-api-poster.pdf)